# SQL Query two joins causing duplicate

Tags: sql-server-2012

*I'll just provide the necessary datas not all of it to avoid confusion
Structure

tbl_job_plist

-jplist_id (PK)
-jplist_position

tbl_prf

-prf_id (PK)
-prf_job_post_ref

tbl_applicant

-ap_id (PK)
-ap_position_applied
-ap_status

Sample Data

tbl_prf

```
prf_id       | prf_job_post_ref |           
---------------------------------
1            |        1         |
3            |        1         |
```

tbl_job_plist

```
jplist_id    | jplist_position     |
------------------------------------
1            |        Crew         |
```

tbl_applicant

```
ap_id        | ap_position_applied | ap_status | ap_name   |
------------------------------------------------------------
1            |        1            |     1     |   Robert  |
```

So here is the flow of the project. First you need to create a Job Posting(tbl_job_plist). Then after that create a Personnel Request(tbl_prf) there you will need to indicate Job Posting Reference so that would be the value of prf_job_post_ref. Other Personnel request can indicate the same job posting. Then an applicant will choose from the list of Job Posting displayed that would be the value of ap_position_applied and gets an ap_status of 1 as a default value.

So If I were to make a query that would view all applicants that has an ap_status of 1 this would be my query

```
SELECT
tbl_applicant.ap_id, 
tbl_applicant.ap_name,
tbl_job_plist.jplist_id, 
tbl_prf.prf_id 
FROM tbl_applicant 
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_plist ON tbl_applicant.ap_position_applied = tbl_job_plist.jplist_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref 
WHERE ap_status = 1
```

The result I'm getting is:

```
ap_id        | jplist_id           | prf_id     | ap_name |
-----------------------------------------------------------
1            |        1            |     1      |   Kurt  |
1            |        1            |     3      |   Kurt  |
```

But I only want to return the result that will not duplicate.

I know because of the

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref
```

I'm getting this result. So I'm asking your suggestions in editing my structure base on the flow that I've provided. Thanks guys

Comment: Why are your tables prefixed with tbl, and separated by underscore?

Comment: @Phill I'm just used to that naming convention

Comment: I'm confused. You are not getting a duplicate here, the data is unique and distinct because of the returned prf_id.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show the duplicate data, you can try GROUP BY.

```
SELECT
tbl_applicant.ap_id, 
tbl_applicant.ap_name,
tbl_job_plist.jplist_id, 
tbl_prf.prf_id 
FROM tbl_applicant 
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_plist ON tbl_applicant.ap_position_applied = tbl_job_plist.jplist_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref
WHERE ap_status = 1 
GROUP BY tbl_applicant.ap_id,tbl_applicant.ap_name, tbl_job_plist.jplist_id,tbl_prf.prf_id
```

OR

You can try use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT
tbl_applicant.ap_id, 
tbl_applicant.ap_name,
tbl_job_plist.jplist_id, 
tbl_prf.prf_id 
FROM tbl_applicant 
LEFT JOIN tbl_job_plist ON tbl_applicant.ap_position_applied = tbl_job_plist.jplist_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref
WHERE ap_status = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you change this to a RIGHT join?

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_prf ON tbl_job_plist.jplist_id = tbl_prf.prf_job_post_ref
```